# Как вывести сообщение в лог консоли YII2?

Tags: yii, yii2

Как вывести сообщение в лог консоли браузера, при использовании YII2?

Comment: так вам в лог или в консоль?

Comment: в лог консоли (в консоль)

Comment: чем вам `echo` не подходит?

Comment: echo - выводит на страницу а не в консоль.

Comment: Так я и спросил, вам в лог файл или вы запускаете через `php yii`

Comment: не, не в лог файл, я ответил выше, а в лог консоли браузера

Comment: ооооо, в вопросе ведь так и было написанно `сообщение в лог консоли YII2?`

Comment: var_dump - говорят это, сейчас проверю

Comment: Да, я со вчера только начал знакомиться с YY2 и не представлял что у неё есть своя собственная консоль. Вопрос, исправил.

Comment: так вам `JS` нужно протестировать? При чем тут `php` фреймворк `Yii`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33497/discussion-between-korytoff-and-).

Comment: Причем JS?  Нет, мне именно нужно выводить в лог сообщения с php кода Yii. Такие логи, обычно которые выводятся во всех языках программирвоания. Допустим что бы что то проверить .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После выяснения подробностей в чате понял, что вопрос про отладку `php` кода в принципе. Итак по порядку:

Первое что всегда использую я для отладки по "живому" это вывод переменной в браузер:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($data);
die('</pre>');
```

Во-вторых почти у всез фреймворков есть свои дебаг панели, у `Yii2` это [Debugger Toolbar](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/) + [статья как настроить](http://borshak.blogspot.ru/2015/04/yii-2-debugger-toolbar.html).

Потом идут более продвинутые варианты через [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) и `IDE`.

Дальше профилирование (логирование и аналитика) через [Yii::Logger](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-logger.html) или же совсем круто через [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org).